# access django site on apache fro another computer

Tags: django, apache

I have a django project up and running on an apache server. I can access and use the site on the server machine.

At the moment, I have the server IP set to 192.168.1.6 and have port 80 open.

When I try to access the site from another machine on the network, instead of the site I get access to the file directory tree. I can see all the files associated with the site (templates and views, etc).

Why is this happening instead of django and apache serving the website as normal?

--edit--
heres some of my configuration settings, btw Its running on ubuntu

htmlfive.wsgi

```
import os
import sys
sys.path = ['/var/www/htmlfive'] + sys.path
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'htmlfive.settings'
import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

/etc/hosts
192.168.1.6 is the network that I'm having the problem with.

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.1.1 ubuntu
192.168.1.6 htmlfive.com 
172.17.107.4 htmlfive.com

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
ff02::3 ip6-allhosts
```

and here is htmlfive.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/daryl/htmlfive.wsgi
DocumentRoot /var/www/htmlfive/htmlfive/
ServerName htmlfive.com
Alias /static /var/www/htmlfive/static/

<Directory /var/www/htmlfive/>
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Paste apache logs and configuration.

Comment: Does this belong on serverfault?

Comment: Sounds like perhaps a lack of a wsgi configuration or a misconfiguration?